# Perlin noise looks streaky and not coherent

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, perlin-noise

Now that my perlin generator is 'working' I created noise, to find that it is nothing like what I see on the internets...
My noise:
[image]

Notice the streaks:
[image]

What I am aiming to get (obviously with corresponding colour):
[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vLxt.png): 
Why does mine look so noisy and nasty?

Code (sorry for no stub, the Perlin noise makes up most of the program so it's important to include the full program):

```
    from PIL import Image
from tkinter import filedialog
from random import randint, random

#Initialise width / height
width = 625
height = 625

#Import gradient picture - 200*1 image used to texture perlin noise
#R,G,B,Alpha
gradient = Image.open("image.png")
gradlist = list(gradient.getdata())

#Create new image
img = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), color=(255, 255, 255, 255))

#Perlin noise modules --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#Modules
from random import sample
from math import floor

p = sample([x for x in range(0, (width * height))], (width * height)) * 2

#Antialising
def fade(t):
    retval = 6*(t**5) - 15*(t**4) + 10*(t**3)
    return retval

#Linear interpolation
def lerp(t,a,b):
    retval = a + (t * (b - a))
    return retval

#Clever bitwise hash stuff - picks a unit vector from 12 possible - (1,1,0),(-1,1,0),(1,-1,0),(-1,-1,0),(1,0,1),(-1,0,1),(1,0,-1),(-1,0,-1),(0,1,1),(0,-1,1),(0,1,-1),(0,-1,-1)
def grad(hash, x, y, z):
    h = hash % 15
    if h < 8:
        u = x
    else:
        u = y
    if h < 4:
        v = y
    elif h in (12, 14):
        v = x
    else:
        v = z
    return (u if (h & 1) == 0 else -u) + (v if (h & 2) == 0 else -v)

#Perlin function
def perlin(x,y,z):
    ix = int(floor(x)) & 255
    iy = int(floor(y)) & 255
    iz = int(floor(z)) & 255
    x -= int(floor(x))
    y -= int(floor(y))
    z -= int(floor(z))
    u = fade(x)
    v = fade(y)
    w = fade(z)
    #Complicated hash stuff
    A = p[ix] + iy
    AA = p[A] + iz
    AB = p[A + 1] + iz
    B = p[ix + 1] + iy
    BA = p[B] + iz
    BB = p[B + 1] + iz
    return -lerp(w, lerp(v, lerp(u, grad(p[AA], x, y, z),grad(p[BA], x - 1, y, z)),lerp(u, grad(p[AB], x, y - 1, z),grad(p[BB], x - 1, y - 1, z))),lerp(v, lerp(u, grad(p[AA + 1], x, y, z - 1),grad(p[BA + 1], x - 1, y, z - 1)), lerp(u, grad(p[AB + 1], x, y - 1, z - 1),grad(p[BB + 1], x - 1, y - 1, z - 1))))


def octavePerlin(x,y,z,octaves,persistence):
    total = 0
    frequency = 1
    amplitude = 1
    maxValue = 0
    for x in range(octaves):
        total += perlin(x * frequency, y * frequency, z * frequency) * amplitude
        maxValue += amplitude
        amplitude *= persistence
        frequency *= 2
    return total / maxValue

z = random()
img.putdata([gradlist[int(octavePerlin((x + random() - 0.5) / 1000, (y + random() - 0.5) / 1000, z, 4, 2) * 100 + 100)] for x in range(width) for y in range(height)])
img.save(filedialog.asksaveasfilename() + ".png", "PNG")
```

Comment: I think you may want to condense it down to a more specific section of code. Looks to me like the color mapping isn't working for you. It seem like things are overflowing. Instead of random numbers, feed in a know number and see if the calculation results in something you would expect.

Comment: @Tammo Heeren I've checked the perlin noise function already, and with known test data it does return the correct value. It could be my color mapping, but again it's the fact that every column has the same colour throughout it

Comment: When I enter Perlin(1,y,3) vs Perlin (1,q, 3), it returns the same value, so it could be in my implementation of Perlin... (p, q are decimals)

Comment: That should probably not happen, but explains what you see in that there is no variation in y.

Comment: I've decided to opt for a prewritten Simplex noise algorithm - Perlin noise does have inherent streakyness, however it shouldnt be this prominent. Thanks anyway :D